# can i use multiple features for multi-class classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Assuming that I have an excel sheet with three columns of data and one column of label. Can I use all three columns of data to train a neural network to predict the label?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Here is a sketch of such a neural network:

[image]